# Using loc to select columns results in some NaNs in row values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, m, that looks like this, and I plan to turn it into training labels after removing a small number of test labels:

```
SampleNbr   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 12155   12156       12157   12158   12159   12165   12166   12167   12168   12169
om_unspec   10.0    8.24    10.0    6.78    10.0    8.54    10.0        10.0    10.0    10.0    ... 2.68    3.37    1.67    1.74    1.25    6.2     5.69    4.2 3.01    1.43
1 rows × 519 columns
```

I have a training set that I've created by removing a fraction of inputs, by column, this way:

```
train_dataset = l.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0, axis=1)
```

The resulting columns left in train_dataset look like this:

```
Int64Index([421, 107, 310, 233, 173,  15, 134, 230, 438,  97,
        ...
        256,  94, 494,  95, 470, 169,  69, 305,  48, 341],
       dtype='int64', length=415)
```

I want to keep the same columns in my training labels as in my training data, so I select from m using training_set columns:

```
train_labels = m.loc[:, train_dataset.columns]
```

But this results in:

```
421 107 310 233 173 15  134 230 438 97  ... 256 94  494 95  470 169 69      305 48  341
om_unspec   NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.0    9.59    NaN NaN NaN 10.0    ... NaN     10.0    NaN NaN NaN 10.0    10.0    NaN NaN NaN
1 rows × 415 columns
```

So, the size is correct, the columns I want are correct, but the row data is mostly NaN. I have a feeling this has to do with m having the 'SampleNbr' index and train_labels NOT having the 'SampleNbr' index, but I don't know how to fix it. If I use iloc, I don't get the right set of columns in the training labels.

Comment: what is `m` ? can you show ?

Comment: SampleNbr   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 12155   12156       12157   12158   12159   12165   12166   12167   12168   12169
om_unspec   10.0    8.24    10.0    6.78    10.0    8.54    10.0        10.0    10.0    10.0    ... 2.68    3.37    1.67    1.74    1.25    6.2     5.69    4.2 3.01    1.43
1 rows × 519 columns

Comment: I'm having some trouble replicating. What is `l` and how is it different than `m`?

Comment: column_names = ['SampleNbr', 'om_unspec', 'A, 'B', C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, usecols=column_names)

    df2 = df.loc[:, ['SampleNbr', 'om_unspec']]
    df2.set_index("SampleNbr", inplace=True)
    df.pop('om_unspec')
    m = df2[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
    m = m.transpose()

    l=[y.set_index('SampleNbr').stack().reset_index(drop=True) for x, y in      df.groupby('SampleNbr')]
    l = pd.concat(l,axis=1)   
... 138 rows × 519 columns

Comment: l is the 'raw data' for the training set, m is the raw data for the training labels

Comment: Why are you working horizontally? I don't really understand what's going on. Isn't it a better idea to transpose your frames first? Run `m.T` for example. Then you can start looking at moving indexes from one to the other frame maybe?

Comment: I've analyzed this some more, and I think what I need to do is be able to "renumber" the columns of m to match those of the columns of l. m has 519 columns and I just want to relabel them 0 to 518

Answer (score -1):

It is some weird behaviour of pandas. To avoid getting NaNs try using .to_numpy() method while you select the columns from the dataframe

```
train_labels = m.loc[:, train_dataset.columns].to_numpy()
```

Comment: "[A]void[ing] getting NaNs" is not something that can be solved by adding [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html). Sure, you could set `na_value=0` or something, but that can hardly be what the OP (years ago) would have wanted to do, and even if that were the case, using `to_numpy` for that is overkill. More in general, nothing in the OP's Q suggests that his/her problem is due to "some weird behaviour of pandas".